# Setting up AWS and Cube.js for Encrypted Connection Between BI Tools and Cube Container

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am working on setting up an AWS infrastructure integrated with Cube, and I need some guidance on how to properly configure it to meet my requirements. Here’s what I’m trying to achieve

### AWS Configuration:

- An ACM certificate linked to the listener of a Network Load Balancer (NLB).
- NLB set up in a public subnet to accept TLS connections on port 54321. The NLB terminates the encryption and forwards TCP traffic on port 54321 to the Cube container.
- Cube container running in a private subnet on AWS Fargate, receiving TCP traffic on port 54321 from the NLB.
- MySQL database container also running on AWS Fargate in a private subnet, accessible by the Cube container over port 3306.

### Goals:

- I want DB client tools or BI tools to connect to Cube (port 54321) using a PostgreSQL connector.
- The connection from the DB client tools or BI tools to Cube (54321) should be encrypted, ensuring encryption from the client up to the NLB.
- The connection from NLB to Cube will be over TCP.

### Issue Encountered:

- When configuring DBeaver (a DB client tool) with the following settings, I am encountering a "Read timed out" error:
  Hostname: Domain name of the ACM certificate
  Port: 54321
- From the NLB logs, it appears that the TLS connection to the NLB is successful.

Could you provide guidance on what configurations are required in AWS and Cube to achieve this setup and possibly resolve the timeout issue?
Thank you for your assistance.